# display no longer listends to console after starting X11, not even after shutting down X11

Tags: x11, freebsd, console, xterm

From the console, or another virtual terminal, I launch X11.  This is in Free BSD.  I cannot return the display to any other terminal afterwards.  By using the ctl-alt-F1 key combination, for example.  Using that key combination seems
to direct the keyboard input into the shell still running on that console, so I can launch another xterminal in the X11 controlled display, or shutdown gracefully, all without seeing what I am typing.

I can kill X11 from the display, or merely kill all apps on it, and even then cannot get the display to echo the output of the keyboard, from any virtual teminal or the console.

Answer (score 1):

With some graphic drivers you cannot switch back to console and sometimes even <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> won't work to enter Xorg again.

This is a bug. The driver is not complete and breaks. Most integrated Intel graphics has this problem and many AMD/ATI, too. So once you enter Xorg, you won't be able to go back to text-based console.

When you really need this functionality, the best chance to make it work is to go with nVidia and the commercial drivers [x11/nvidia-driver](https://www.freshports.org/x11/nvidia-driver).